# Why do I see double occurrence of a column in the SQL Server table in SQL Developer tool?

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a tool by Oracle called SQL Developer. I have created a table called `multicarrier_ClaimTraceDetails`. Before this I tried creating the same table with name (actually same name but with lower case, which I had to delete it and create this new one). But when I to see the structure of table, I see every column twice in the table.

I have below questions about this behavior:

1. Why is it happening?
2. How can I correct it?
3. Didn't my previous/old table got deleted? (though I don't see it in the list of tables in left panel)

[image]

Comment: Does that table exist in more than one schema in SQL Server? Did you `commit` the `drop table`?

Comment: The table does exist with same name in dbo schema, and I dont remeber doing any commit while creating the new table

Comment: I don't use SQL Developer, but if I recall correctly it defaults to having autocommit off. As SQL Server supports transactional DDL, you have to commit the `drop table` to _really_ get rid of the table (if you did turn on autocommit, then of course that would not be necessary).

Comment: If you use Oracle SQL Developer, that suggests you use Oracle, rather then sql-server. Please clarify your tags.

Comment: What version of SQL server and please share the ddl you used. Assuming SSMS doesn't show the same...